# D3D Texture convert Format

Tags: cuda, direct3d, pixel-shader

I have a D3D11 Texture2d with the format `DXGI_FORMAT_R10G10B10A2_UNORM` and want to convert this into a D3D11 Texture2d with a `DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT` or `DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UINT` format, as those textures can only be imported into CUDA.

For performance reasons I want this to fully operate on the GPU. I read some threads suggesting, I should set the second texture as a render target and render the first texture onto it or to convert the texture via a pixel shader.

But as I don't know a lot about D3D I wasn't able to do it like that.
In an ideal world I would be able to do this stuff without setting up a whole rendering pipeline including IA, VS, etc...

Does anyone maybe has an example of this or any hints?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is size of texture? When you convert 32 bit format (first one) into 128bit format (second one), doesn't it put more stress on the GPU caches as it makes 4x size? What if re-computing it on the fly is faster than converting it and accessing it from cache? (assuming GPU is not compressing the texture by default)

Comment: Oh yeah that's right but technically a DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UINT format would be fine too - it just has to be a format that can be imported in CUDA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the GPU, the way you do this conversion is a render-to-texture which requires at least a minimal 'offscreen' rendering setup.

1. Create a render target view (`DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT`, `DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UINT`, etc.). The restriction here is it needs to be a format supported as a render target view on your Direct3D Hardware Feature level. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/overviews-direct3d-11-devices-downlevel-intro).
2. Create a SRV for your source texture. Again, needs to be supported as a texture by your Direct3D Hardware device feature level.
3. Render the source texture to the RTV as a 'full-screen quad'. with Direct3D Hardware Feature Level 10.0 or greater, you can have the quad self-generated in the Vertex Shader so you don't really need a Vertex Buffer for this. See [this code](https://github.com/microsoft/Xbox-ATG-Samples/tree/master/Kits/ATGTK/FullScreenQuad).

Given your are starting with `DXGI_FORMAT_R10G10B10A2_UNORM`, then you pretty much require Direct3D Hardware Feature Level 10.0 or better. That actually makes it pretty easy. You still need to actually get a full rendering pipeline going, although you don't need a 'swapchain'.

> You may find [this tutorial](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Using-HDR-rendering) helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and hints but I still can't get my render to work - the output texture is always empty (only 0). The RTV itself works (if I use clearRTV to fill it with a certain color, I can see that in the output texture (via copying it into a staging texture then reading it)).
Can you maybe have a look at my code? (https://gist.github.com/LRK321/a77a7d9af73a6dc5e567e8b44d8780be) 
That would be great! Thanks in advance

Comment: You should enable the Direct3D Debug Device and look for any output. It may be the original *CopyResource* failed.

Comment: I already thought I had enabled the Debug Device but it was only for D3D12. Through enabling the debug device I got the warning that a viewport is missing. After adding a viewport the rendering finally worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad you got it working. If you want to continue to the *DirectX Tool Kit* (you are using the ``CommonStates`` class), you could use the ``BasicPostProcess`` class in "Copy" mode which is going to do exactly the same thing, but handles the VS, PS, etc. settings mostly for you. https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/BasicPostProcess

Comment: I'll have a look into it. Thanks!